# Why doesn't lapply work on S4 objects which have an as.list.default method?

Tags: r, class, lapply, r-s4

Suppose I have a vector-like S4 class:

```
.MyClass <- setClass("MyClass", representation(a="numeric", b="character"))

setMethod("[", c("MyClass", "numeric", "missing"), function(x, i, j, ...) {
  do.call(initialize, c(x, sapply(slotNames(x), function(y) slot(x, y)[i],
          simplify=FALSE)))
})

setMethod("length", "MyClass", function(x) length(x@a))
```

And say I have also defined methods for `as.list` and `as.list.default`:

```
setGeneric("as.list")
setMethod("as.list", "MyClass",
          function(x) lapply(seq_along(x), function(i) x[i]))
setGeneric("as.list.default")
setMethod("as.list.default", "MyClass",
          function(x) lapply(seq_along(x), function(i) x[i]))
```

Now given an object of this class, `myobj`:

```
myobj <- .MyClass(a=1:4, b=letters[1:4])
```

When I use `lapply`, it complains:

```
> lapply(myobj, function(i) rep(i@b, i@a))
Error in as.list.default(X) : 
  no method for coercing this S4 class to a vector
```

But if I use `as.list.default`, the function gives the desired output:

```
> lapply(as.list.default(myobj), function(i) rep(i@b, i@a))
[[1]]
[1] "a"

[[2]]
[1] "b" "b"
...
```

Why does `lapply` not work even though I have defined a method for `as.list.default` for the class?

Obviously I can manually define a `lapply` method for the class and it will work fine (below), but I was wondering where the error is actually being encountered. Why is `lapply` attempting to coerce my object into a vector even though the function it is calling should be turning the object into a list?

```
setGeneric("lapply")
setMethod("lapply", c("MyClass", "function"), function(X, FUN, ...) {
  lapply(as.list(X), FUN, ...)
})
lapply(myobj, function(i) rep(i@b, i@a))
```

Comment: No need to redefine the generics here . Otherwise amazing your code should work fine .

Comment: I usually create generics so I don't see the `Creating a generic function for ...` messages. I could use `sink` or `capture.output`, but that seems messier than just defining generics.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From the `?Methods` help page, a workable strategy seems to be

```
#same
.MyClass <- setClass("MyClass", representation(a="numeric", b="character"))

setMethod("[", c("MyClass", "numeric", "missing"), function(x, i, j, ...) {
  do.call(initialize, c(x, sapply(slotNames(x), function(y) slot(x, y)[i],
          simplify=FALSE)))
})

setMethod("length", "MyClass", function(x) length(x@a))

#different
as.list.MyClass <-function(x) {
    lapply(seq_along(x), function(i) x[i])
}
setMethod("as.list", "MyClass", as.list.MyClass)

#test
myobj <- .MyClass(a=1:4, b=letters[1:4])
lapply(myobj, function(i) rep(i@b, i@a))

# [[1]]
# [1] "a"
# 
# [[2]]
# [1] "b" "b"
# 
# [[3]]
# [1] "c" "c" "c"
# 
# [[4]]
# [1] "d" "d" "d" "d"
```

Comment: No need to use `setMethod` here. You just coerce your S4 object using the generic S3 method as.list.

Comment: @agstudy So did i misinterpret the `?Methods` help page? or it is it wrong? (I agree that it's not required to get `lapply` to work, but it seems like it's just a best practice.)

Comment: honestly I didn't read the help.  But it is a good practice to use the S3 function as S4 method for coercion(maintenance reason). Just my remark to show that you don't answer the question in strictly S4 manner, it is good workaround.

Comment: Nice. The documentation was very helpful in explaining why this works.